# Auto DST for Marketing Cloud accounts

Tags: marketing-cloud, timezone

Does Marketing Cloud automatically switch all relevant user accounts when Day Light Saving time occurs? (i.e. their user account timezone is changed)

Comment: Do you mean server storage of data (date in Data Extensions/Data Views), or do you mean User Interface side (Send times, scheduled automations, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, it’s indicated by * on the user account time zone settings.

Answer (score 0):

On checking, I guess Salesforce handles the same.

If I set our default timezone (in Company Information) to "(GMT-04:00) Eastern Daylight Time (America/New_York)", then it will automatically change to "(GMT-05:00) Eastern Standard Time (America/New_York)" in November when Daylight Savings for New York ends.

(Confirmed with Salesforce support)

Thread: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000DsMjQAK

Comment: Is this for Salesforce CRM or Marketing Cloud? Even if its CRM, I have an account which is currently GMT that hasn't switched to BST (it should have done, 12 days ago).